# makefile filename manipulations

Tags: makefile, suffix, basename

I'm trying to extract the `6` from a file called `~/Downloads/GGG/some_file.6.txt` in `makefile`. I got pretty close, and managed to get `.6`, but I can't seem to get rid of the dot `.` and get just the `6`. Here is my makefile:

```
FILE = ~/Downloads/GGG/some_file.6.txt

another_file.txt: ${FILE}
    @echo $<
    @echo $(suffix $(basename $<))
    @cp $< $@
```

Here is the result:

```
$ make
/home/oren/Downloads/GGG/some_file.6.txt
.6
```

How can I get rid of the dot?

Comment: If you have more and more complex string manipulations to complete, you may take a look at [the GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt). See e.g. an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087491/make-detect-platform-with-regex/58092842#58092842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
@echo $(patsubst .%,%,$(suffix $(basename $<)))
```